# Converting a first order quantized boundary condition to a second quantized boundary condition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, boundary-conditions, second-quantization

### Background

So there is a recipe to convert a First Quantised $\leftrightarrow $ Second Quantised Theory (we are following these Ashok Sen's Quantum Field Theory I of HRI institute's [notes](http://www.hri.res.in/%7Esen/QFT1_lectures.pdf)). Unfortunately Professor Ashok does not mention recipe of  converting a  First Quantised Boundary Condition $\leftrightarrow $ Second Quantised Theory Boundary Theory?

### Question

What's the method to convert first quantized boundary condition to a second order boundary condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs the boundary conditions in order to solve, e.g., Schrödinger equation for the wave functions, which then serve as a basis for the second quantization as:
$$
\hat{\psi}(x)=\sum_n\phi_n(x)a_n
$$
The second quantized wave function is then in the Fock space (the space of filling numbers) - it is not a continuous function, and the usual notion of boundary conditions does not apply. One could think of some situations which could be referred to as *"boundary conditions"*, but these are unrelated to the boundary conditions of first quantization, which have been already applied.

Comment: So let's say we are talking about bosons. And we have symmetric boundary conditions of the sort $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_n) = f(x_2,x_1,x_3,x_n) = 0$ then this wont have any corresponding QFT boundary condition?